# how can I start an app with last closed settings?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

In my code, there are Spinners for countries and their cities. When I start app, the lists of Spinners are ordering alphabetically.

The application will be opened with the last closed settings. For example:
If we select France for country and Paris for city from spinners.
Then, exit from app. Start again. First element of `state_spin` will be France, `city_spin` will be Paris.

how can I do it. thanks..

```
     state_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);         
     city_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

     new spinner1_countries(context,UrlMain,arrayAdpt_state,state_spin).execute();
                //to get state lists from a website        

     state_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              final String[] stateList = spinner1_countries.stateList;

              new spinner2_city(context, arrayAdpt_state,city_spin).execute(); //to get city lists

            }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }        });

     city_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     ......
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the previously selected options in `SharedPreferences`. When your app starts again, load these default values from `SharedPreferences` and set them as default for your selectors.

Find a nice tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 2):

When the User selects something in the spinner, save the position to SharedPreferences:

```
 @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
      SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putInt("1st_spinner", position);
                editor.apply();
        }
```

When Your app is started get the position an set the spinner:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
int position = sp.getInt("1st_spinner", 1);
state_spin.setSelection(position);
```